# Java Structure to Map C sockaddr_in Structure through JNI

Tags: java, sockets, java-native-interface

Is there a Java class that maps (via JNI) to the C sockaddr_in structure? I have a C method that returns a sockaddr_in structure and I'm unsure what Java Object can be used to map to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InetAddress or SocketAddress, or one of their derived classes, but I'd like to know exactly what you mean by 'handle'.

Comment: I edited my question as it was not worded correctly.  I need to know the structure that I can use in my JNI classes to map to the C sockaddr_in.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an `java.net.InetSocketAddress`.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html

HTH

Comment: Your note is incorrect. `sockaddr_in` is the IPv4 version of `sockaddr`.